# Update all matching rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have used the below script for many projects.  The way it works is I have a spreadsheet set up as a form (in this case, cells in Y2:Y7) that updates values in P22:U if the value in Y2 matches a value in P22:P. If the value  in Y2 is not found, then a new row is appended.

However, I am not sure how to update every row that has a match.  In the case of multiple rows with the same value, this script only updates the very last matching row.

Here is the script:

```
function settings() {
      
       var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
      lock.waitLock(20000);
      // DO SOMETHING
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      lock.releaseLock();
      
      // source spreadsheets
      var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      
    
      var values = sheet.getRange("Y2:Y7").getValues().reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a.concat(b)
    });
    var valuesToSearch = values[0];
    var row;
    sheet.getRange(22,16,sheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().forEach(function (r, i) {
        if (r[0] === valuesToSearch) {
          row = i + 22;
        }
      })
    row = row ? row : sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var data = sheet.getRange(row, 16, 1, 6).getValues()[0].map(function (el, ind){
      return el = values[ind] ? values[ind] : el;
      })
    
    var statusValue = sheet.getRange("Y2:Y7").getValue();   //added
    
    if (statusValue != '') {                       //added
    sheet.getRange(row, 16, 1, 6).setValues([data]);   //added
    
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert( 'Settings for Machine #'+  sheet.getRange('Y2').getValue() + ' have been updated.');
    
    }
    }
```

Here is a screenshot sample of the form:

[image: Screenshot1]

And here is a screenshot sample of the data after running my script:

[image: Screenshot2]

Note how the last row was updated, but not the row above, despite the fact that the Machine # is the same.

(Sorry.  I can't share actual spreadsheets, even with dummy data, outside of the organization.)

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample spreadsheet with dummy values, and also your current output and expected output so that we can further help with your question?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Shared screenshots.  Sorry, I couldn't get the dummy data and screenshots put together by the end of the work day on Friday.  Hope that helps.  Also sorry that I can't share actual spreadsheets due to company privacy concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your showing script and your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function settings() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values1 = sheet.getRange("Y2:Y7").getValues().map(([x]) => x);
  var range = sheet.getRange(22, 16, sheet.getLastRow() - 21, 6);
  var values2 = range.getValues();
  if (values2.find(([p]) => p == values1[0])) {
    values2 = values2.map(r => r[0] == values1[0] ? values1 : r);
  } else {
    values2.push(values1);
    range = range.offset(0, 0, values2.length, values2[0].length);
  }
  range.setValues(values2);
}
```

- When this script is run, the cells "P2:U" are updated with the values of "Y2:Y7" by checking the cell values of "Y2" and "P2:P".

### Added:

About your following new question,

> However, why do rows get added to the bottom of the spreadsheet? I had 196 rows before running the script After the script is run and a row is updated, I have 500 rows.

In this case, I guessed that the last row of columns "P" to "U" might be different from other columns. If my guess is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function settings() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values1 = sheet.getRange("Y2:Y7").getValues().map(([x]) => x);
  var range = sheet.getRange(22, 16, sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(16) - 21, 6);
  var values2 = range.getValues();
  if (values2.find(([p]) => p == values1[0])) {
    values2 = values2.map(r => r[0] == values1[0] ? values1 : r);
  } else {
    values2.push(values1);
    range = range.offset(0, 0, values2.length, values2[0].length);
  }
  range.setValues(values2);
}
```

- In this sample script, the last row of column "P" is retrieved using `get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom`.

Comment: Looks like you understood my question just fine. Thank you. It works exactly as requested.

Comment: However, why do rows get added to the bottom of the spreadsheet?  I had 196 rows before running the script  After the script is run and a row is updated, I have 500 rows.

Comment: @Codedabbler Thank you for replying. About `Looks like you understood my question just fine. Thank you. It works exactly as requested.`, I understood your issue was resolved. About new question of `However, why do rows get added to the bottom of the spreadsheet? I had 185 rows. After a row gets updated, I have 500 rows`, I would like to support you. But, I do not know your actual Spreadsheet. So, I cannot propose a clear answer to your new question. If you want only my guess, I'm worried that the last row might be different from columns "P" to "U" and other columns. How about confirming it?

Comment: @Codedabbler If my guess of your actual Spreadsheet is correct, for example, when you want to retrieve the last row of the specific column, you can see the script for it in my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639

Comment: @Codedabbler Although, unfortunately, I do not know your actual Spreadsheet, I added one more sample script for your new question. But, my answer to your new question is just my guess. If this was not the direct solution to your new question, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to try to correctly understand your new question.

Comment: This morning, I added screenshots to original question, per request for sample spreadsheet.  Can't share spreadsheets per company privacy concerns.

Comment: Will look at your added script.

Comment: @Codedabbler Thank you for replying. About `I added screenshots to original question, per request for sample spreadsheet. Can't share spreadsheets per company privacy concerns.`, I added one more sample script for your new question. About `Will look at your added script.`, please confirm it. If that was not the direct solution to your new question, can you post it as a new question by including more information? If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Now I only get 1 additional row...much closer to desired results.

Comment: @Codedabbler About `Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new question was resolved.`, thank you for replying. I'm glad your new question was resolved.